# Android navigation system/bar square button

Tags: android, navigationbar

I do not find on Internet, what is the name of this button ?

[image]

And I want to know what is the exact action when an application is deleted like this :

With this action, the application is not really stopped

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Third Image means Square is called `Overview button`(`Recent Button`). When Click on That `Button` the list of application is display which you are work on it. and you can simply remove app from the list by slide app `Right` to `Left`.

For more detail visit this : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32697/what-is-the-offical-name-of-the-third-on-screen-button